# Why is my AMD Quad 645 CPU running at 800MHz per core on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: performance, cpu, ati, benchmarks

I've just loaded Ubuntu 12.04 onto a brand box with an AMD 645 quad CPU with 8GB RAM.
In the BIOS it says, the CPU is running at 3100MHz. However when i boot into Ubuntu 12.04 it says 800MHz?

I've checked using: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` command from the terminal and running **System profiler and benchmark** application. Both say 800Mhz at each core?

Any ideas or input would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's power saving. Read this screenshot in detail: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqi5X.png.  Should I be suing intel? :P

Comment: @izx You may want to turn this into an answer...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this happens to many users using latest AMD CPUs and Ubuntu.
Modern CPUs try to consume less power when the full performance capability is not required. Ubuntu ships some drivers which can handle this ability and rise the performance if necessary.

Have a look at this forum thread if you want to know some details:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505495

Comment: I have checked into it and i concur, that seems the most likely answer to the question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate it if you could mark my reply as the correct one!